# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children') at window.onload

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am trying to get the children of a div, however, for some reason, it won't work.

I get the div via the getElementById method and then when I try to get the children of that element, it won't recognize it and throws me an error

```js
window.onload = function(){
    console.log("h")
    for (i in bookData ){
        var current = bookData[i]
        var currentCodeN = current.codeName
        var currentHTMLElem = document.getElementById(toString(currentCodeN))
        console.log(typeof(currentHTMLElem)) //returns 'object'
        console.log(typeof(currentHTMLElem.children)); //error
        console.log(currentHTMLElem.children.length);
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? Searched for this issue and set up an event to wait for the whole page to be loaded. Still doesn't work

Error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children')
    at window.onload"
```

I am not using iFrame

UPDATE: I was using toString on an already string. Sorry.

Comment: `typeof(null)` returns 'object'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

```
var currentHTMLElem = document.getElementById(toString(currentCodeN))
```

This is making currentHTMLElem `null`. Will get back to why, but it is clearly null because the error message tells you it is.

```
console.log(typeof(currentHTMLElem)) //returns 'object'
```

Yes, if currentHTMLElem is null, `typeof` will return `"object"`. So there you are.

I don't know what `bookData` is, but I'm sure using `toString` is incorrect. Look at what `toString` does for various objects:

`toString(null)` -> `"[object Undefined]"`

`toString(12)` -> `"[object Undefined]"`

`toString(anythingatall)` -> `"[object Undefined]"`

That's because you are calling the wrong `toString`. Calling `toString` without an object will use the base `Object.prototype.toString` with an undefined object. If you invoke it with an object like `toString.apply(12)` you will get the base version which just tells you the type (`[Object Number]`). Instead, you would want to call the overloaded version:  `currentCodeN.toString()`, which will call to toString for whatever type `currentCodeN` is. For a string, this just returns the string, for a Number it will return a string version.

However, that will raise an error is `currentCodeN` is null or undefined. You shouldn't need to use `toString` at all. I'm guessing it is already a string, so try just:

```
var currentHTMLElem = document.getElementById(current.codeName)
```

or for maximum safety:

```
var currentHTMLElem = document.getElementById(current && current.codeName || '')
```

if that still gives you `null`, then the element doesn't exist in the DOM.